# Remove YYYY_MM_DD_HH_MM from filename

Tags: bash

We have few csv and xml files in following formats

```
String_YYYY_MM_DD_HH_MM.csv

String_YYYY_MM_DD_HH_MM.xml

String.xml

String.csv
```

Examples:

```
Reference_Categories_2021_02_24_17_14.csv
CD_CategoryTree_2021_02_24_17_14.csv
New_Categories.xml
Mobile_Footnote_2021_03_05_16_21.csv
Campaign_Version_2018_09_24_20_00.xml
Campaign_new.csv
```

Now we have to remove **_YYYY_MM_DD_HH_MM** from filenames so result will be

```
Reference_Categories.csv
CD_CategoryTree.csv
New_Categories.xml
Mobile_Footnote.csv
Campaign_Version.xml
Campaign_new.csv
```

Any idea how to do that in bash?

Answer (score 3):

In pure bash:

```
pat='_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9]'

for f in *$pat*.{csv,xml}; do echo mv "$f" "${f/$pat}"; done
```

Delete the `echo` if the output looks fine.

Answer (score 2):

With `bash` Something like:

```
shopt -s nullglob

for f in *.{xml,csv}; do
  ext="${f##*.}"
  [[ "${f%%_[0-9]*}" = *.@(xml|csv) ]] && continue
  echo mv -v -- "$f" "${f%%_[0-9]*}.$ext"
done
```

---

With the `=~` operator and `BASH_REMATCH`

```
shopt -s nullglob

regexp='^(.{1,})(_[[:digit:]]{4}_[[:digit:]]{2}_[[:digit:]]{2}_[[:digit:]]{2}_[[:digit:]]{2})([.].*)$'

for f in *.{xml,csv}; do
  [[ "$f" =~ $regexp ]] &&
  echo mv -v -- "$f" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${BASH_REMATCH[-1]}"
done
```

---

- Remove the `echo` if you're satisfied with the output.

Answer (score -1):

Using `bash`, `find`, and `awk`:

Use `find` to find files with .csv or .xml suffix in the current directory.  Pipe the `find` output to `awk` and create the `mv` commands that are output and passed to `bash`.

```
bash < <(find * -type f \( -name '*.csv' -o -name '*.xml' \) | awk '{orig=$0; gsub(/_[0-9]{4}_[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{2}/,""); print "mv "orig" "$0}')
```

Directory contents before:

```
find * -type f
CD_CategoryTree_2021_02_24_17_14.csv
Campaign_Version_2018_09_24_20_00.xml
Campaign_new.csv
Mobile_Footnote_2021_03_05_16_21.csv
New_Categories.xml
Reference_Categories_2021_02_24_17_14.csv
```

Directory contents after:

```
find * -type f
CD_CategoryTree.csv
Campaign_Version.xml
Campaign_new.csv
Mobile_Footnote.csv
New_Categories.xml
Reference_Categories.csv
```